# Color differences between cocoa and photoshop

Tags: cocoa, macos, colors, photoshop

I'm having some trouble with colors in interface builder and cocoa.

I build out my interface in photoshop, and when I copy the RGB values from photoshop and set my UI elements in interface builder, or through code, the colors are not even close. I've messed around with setting color profiles in photoshop but can't seem to find one that makes a difference (maybe I'm just using them wrong)

Can anyone lend a hand as to how to set photoshop to more accurately depict the colors used by cocoa? This is what I mean:

[image]

I created a box in interface builder and set its RGB to 50, 100, 150, then took a screenshot of it and pasted it into photoshop. Then I created another box in photoshop and set its rgb value to 50, 100, 150. If I sample the IB color, it's RGB comes out to 63, 120, 163.

Comment: Sounds like it could be a gamma issue..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Photoshop *colour settings* choose a *working space* of

> ColorSync RGB - Generic RGB Profile

Create a new Ps document, in the 'new' dialogue box open up the 'Advanced' tab, for *Color Profile*:

> Generic RGB Profile

In the Ps *View menu* make sure you don't have "Proof Colors" enabled.

You should be good to go.

Comment: Perfect. Worked great. Thanks!